# VBA code to copy value from one cell to specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and need help for the following:

1. Copy value from cell B3, B4, B5, B6, B7 in Worksheet "WORKING"
2. paste the value those of cells to Range (F2, lastrow), (G2, lastrow), (H2, last row), (I2, lastrow), (J2, lastrow) respectively in Worksheet "TRACKING"

*The "lastrow" in Worksheet "TRACKING" will always vary

*cell B3, B4, B5, B6, B7 will always have different values

For example

Sheets"WORKING"

```
B3 is A1234
B4 is A
B5 is B
B6 is 1
B7 is XX
```

Sheets"TRACKING"
lastrow determined to be 4 using code `lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Output desired is shown below

```
           F         G         H         I         J
(Row 1)
(row 2)   A1234      A         B         1         XX
(row 3)   A1234      A         B         1         XX
(row 4)   A1234      A         B         1         XX
```

Hope someone can help me out!! thanks!!

SOLUTION FOUND

```
Sub data_transpose
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set copyRng = Worksheets("WORKING").Range("B3:B7")
Set sh = Worksheets("TRACKING")

lastrow = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1

For i = 2 To lastrow
copyRng.Copy
sh.Cells(i, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,    
_SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to record a macro? This will give you a good place to start

Comment: Tried record marco but didn't achieve what I want... I was playing with arrays (from answers found here) but it didn't achieve what I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might work for you

```
for jj=1 to #number_of_lines_you_want
for j = 6 to 10
   for i = 3 to worksheets("WORKING").cells(2,2).End(xlDown).Row
        lastrow = worksheets("TRACKING").cells(2,j).End(xlDown).Row
        worksheets("TRACKING").cells(i,j) = worksheets("WORKING").cells(i,2).value
   next i
next j
next jj
```

the end(xlDown).row will give you the row of the last entry.

What about this?

```
for i = 3 to 7
worksheets("WORKING").range("B3:B7").Copy
Worksheets("TRACKING").cells(i,6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Hi hi! i tired the code but it seem to only add one row only.. I edited my question perhaps it might make it clearer what i want to achieve

Comment: Do you know how many times you want to add the lines to "TRACKING"?

Comment: hi faurillou, your method got me thinking about transpose, moving down the row and I have found a workable solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option to get you started:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim copyRng As Range, cl As Range, col As Integer, lastRow As Integer

    Set copyRng = Worksheets("Working").Range("B3:B7")
    col = 6 ' Denotes column F

    With Worksheets("Tracking")
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cl In copyRng
            .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(lastRow, col)) = cl
            col = col + 1
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Alex!!! I tried your code but it seems to only add at the last row only.. your idea got me thinking to set it up as a loop via setting `dim row as integer` and then under 

`for row = 1 to lastrow
For Each cl In copyRng
targetRng.offset(0, col) = cl
col = col + 1
Next cl
next row`

too bad it doesn't work so means there is something wrong with my code.. would you be able to help?

Comment: @IsabelLim - see updated code. I think this achieves what you need.

Comment: hey alex thx so much for helping!! your method got me thinking about vba fundamental! haha i found a workable solution to suit my needs.. definitely not elegant but nonetheless it was what i wanted

Comment: That's great. Sounds like you've advanced your knowledge of VBA which is a good outcome regardless of whether you have an elegant solution!